# Vim: How can I :cd to an sftp directory?

Tags: sftp, vim, emacs

I'm currently an emacs user, but thought I would come back and take another look at Vim for fun.

My client machine is Ubuntu, and I frequently work on other ubuntu servers within my network, emacs and tramp is really nice in this regard, I can just connect to a file via sftp and then easily navigate to it's parents/children/sibling, just as if I was dealing with a file on the local file system.

With Vim I can sftp to a file, but none of the navigation stuff works, when I use :e or fuzzy file search, vim still thinks I'm back on the client machine. If I try to :cd to the sftp directory I get an error.

Is there anyway I can get the same file/folder navigation regardless of whether I'm looking at an sftp folder or a folder on my client machine?

Cheers,

Chrsi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mount the SFTP folder in nautilus it will show up under `~/.gvfs` and any app can access the files there.

Comment: Wow, I never knew about the .gvfs folder before. Very cool, not just for my current problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but what works for me is to log into the other machine with ssh, usually into a GNU Screen session: "ssh -t user@host screen" once there, I open up vim in one terminal and do other work in another terminal. I usually end up with a couple of instances of vim for different files.